# How to crop a numpy 2d array to non-zero values?

Tags: arrays, numpy, crop

Let's say i have a 2d boolean numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
], dtype=bool)
```

How can i in general crop it to the smallest box (rectangle, kernel) that includes all True values?

So in the example above:

```
b = np.array([
    [1,0,1],
    [1,1,0],
], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Does it have to be 3x3 like in the example or the size can vary? Should it be n x n or can be n x m?

Comment: sorry, n x m... i'll modify the example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one with slicing and `argmax` to get the bounds -

```
def smallestbox(a):
    r = a.any(1)
    if r.any():
        m,n = a.shape
        c = a.any(0)
        out = a[r.argmax():m-r[::-1].argmax(), c.argmax():n-c[::-1].argmax()]
    else:
        out = np.empty((0,0),dtype=bool)
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [142]: a
Out[142]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]])

In [143]: smallestbox(a)
Out[143]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])

In [144]: a[:] = 0

In [145]: smallestbox(a)
Out[145]: array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=bool)

In [146]: a[2,2] = 1

In [147]: smallestbox(a)
Out[147]: array([[ True]])
```

**Benchmarking**

Other approach(es) -

```
def argwhere_app(a): # @Jörn Hees's soln
    coords = np.argwhere(a)
    x_min, y_min = coords.min(axis=0)
    x_max, y_max = coords.max(axis=0)
    return a[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1]
```

Timings for varying degrees of sparsity (approx. 10%, 50% & 90%) -

```
In [370]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(5000,5000)>0.1

In [371]: %timeit argwhere_app(a)
     ...: %timeit smallestbox(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 310 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.19 ms per loop

In [372]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(5000,5000)>0.5

In [373]: %timeit argwhere_app(a)
     ...: %timeit smallestbox(a)
1 loop, best of 3: 324 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.21 ms per loop

In [374]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.rand(5000,5000)>0.9

In [375]: %timeit argwhere_app(a)
     ...: %timeit smallestbox(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.19 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 14):

After some more fiddling with this, i actually found a solution myself:

```
coords = np.argwhere(a)
x_min, y_min = coords.min(axis=0)
x_max, y_max = coords.max(axis=0)
b = cropped = a[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1]
```

The above works for boolean arrays out of the box. In case you have other conditions like a threshold `t` and want to crop to values larger than t, simply modify the first line:

```
coords = np.argwhere(a > t)
```

Comment: Great answer. I would just replace "x" with "col" and "y" with "row" in the variable names. Working with images, you often have to use the convention of using "y" as the first index.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.transpose(a[np.sum(a,1) != 0])
a = np.transpose(a[np.sum(a,1) != 0])
```

It's not the quickest but it's alright.

Comment: If there's a blank line horizontally or vertically, it  will remove that too. It's not 100% clear on this question though, if that's what OP wants or otherwise.

Comment: @Divakar ouch, true! I'll put my celebratory cookie back in the jar (