# How to (generally!) deal with out-of-range output pixel destinations

Tags: python, image, opencv, transform

I'm working on a perspective transform application involving transforming 3D points to 2D camera pixels. It is a purely mathematical model, because I'm preparing to use it on hardware that I don't really have access to (so I'm making up focal length and offset values for the intrinsic camera matrix).

When I do the mapping, depending on the xyz location of the camera, I get huge differences in where my transformed image is, and I have to make the matrix where I'm inputting the pixels really large. (I'm mapping an image of 1000x1000 pixels to an image of about 600x600 pixels, but its located around 6000, so I have to make my output matrix 7000x7000, which takes a long time to plt.imshow. I have no use for the actual location of the pixels, because I'm only concerned with what the remapped image looks like.

I was wondering how people dealt with this issue: 
I can think of just cropping the image down to the area that is non-zero (where my pixels are actually mapped too? Like seen in:

[How to crop a numpy 2d array to non-zero values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987774/how-to-crop-a-numpy-2d-array-to-non-zero-values)

but that still requires me to use space and time to alot a 7000x7000 destination matrix

Comment: is it about 3d to 2d (see binary space partitioning, frustum culling and other techniques used in efficient gaming engines) or about image to image warping (see bounding boxes and subimaging)?

Comment: how many points are you processing? Maybe it is more efficient to save the projected points in a list?

Comment: I'm processing about a million points. A list could work, then I could find the min x and y value and then subtract every point from the min's to get a cropped image. I wonder if that would be faster, because I know lists can take a while

Comment: not sure about python, in C++ you could use vectors. If you have 7000x7000 images you're basically processing 49 mio pixels, so there is a good chance to increase speed, even if images are optimized and lists are not. Maybe you could even use some "sparse matrix" representations, if they are available in numpy/python. I would give both approaches a try. I think the general idea is to find the bounding box/rect of your projected points, so it could even give a speed up if you 1. project all 3D points and just remember min/max positions 2. project again in translated space and optimal imagesize