# Map Object to Circle in Python, OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

Given a numpy array that contains a grey scale image of a segmented object. The numpy array has dimensions `(32,32)`. The background of this object is coded as zeros, the object itself has a number between (0,255]. 
Example (with dimensions `(7,7)`):

```py
# Input
> np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,2,2,2,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

The object in the numpy array can have an arbitrary shape.
I'd like to stretch (distort) the object such that it becomes a circle, regardless of its previous shape. The circle should fill the entire 32x32 array. The values should be linearly interpolated.
Example (simplified, without linear interpolation):

```py
# Desired output = Circle with linearly interpolated values
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

How would I do that. Is there maybe an OpenCV function to distort objects to circles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets divide your problem in 3 steps:

1. Resize your image to 32x32
2. Remap your matrix from a square to circle
3. Trim edges and resize if necessary

**Resize your image to 32x32**

You can use the [`cv2.resize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize) to make the job for you. It will do all the necessary interpolation to make the image the size you want

```
square = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,2,2,2,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
resized_image = cv2.resize(square, (32, 32))
```

[image: resize]

**Remap your matrix from a square to circle**

Mathematically speaking there are many ways to create a transformation from a square matrix to a circle. There is a very interesting topic about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621831/how-can-i-convert-coordinates-on-a-square-to-coordinates-on-a-circle). Basically, you have to define a function to go from a set of points `[x, y]` to another set of points `[u, v]`, one possible solution mentioned by Ch Fong is:

> u = x √(x² + y² - x²y²) / √(x² + y²)
>
> v = y √(x² + y² - x²y²) / √(x² + y²)

You can use this equation with [`cv2.remap()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#void%20remap(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20map1,%20InputArray%20map2,%20int%20interpolation,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue)) function to obtain the transformation you want. However there is a tool called [`squircle`](https://pypi.org/project/squircle/) that do all the work for you! By reading their doc, you can make a simple code to make this transformation:

Import with:

```
from squircle import to_circle 
from PIL import Image
```

Call the transformation after opening the image:

```
circle = to_circle(square)
```

[image: remmaped]

**Trim edges and resize if necessary**

Now, you just have to trim all zeros from your matrix, and resize it again so all 32x32 matrix have content inside it. A solution you can use is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987831/11522398) where `circle` is your remapped image. After you cut all initial and final lines and columns that are all zeros, you have to resize it again to 32x32.

```
coords = np.argwhere(circle)
x_min, y_min = coords.min(axis=0)
x_max, y_max = coords.max(axis=0)
b = cropped = circle[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1]
resized_cropped_image = cv2.resize(cropped, (32, 32))
```

[image: trimmed]

### **Complete examples**

---

**Example 1 - Using your array:**

[image: yourexample]

---

**Example 2 - Using another image:**

[image: myexample]

You can find [a Jupyter Notebook for this example](https://github.com/leomariga/StackOverflowSolutions/blob/master/Square_to_circle.ipynb) in my Github page. The full code can be seen below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from squircle import to_circle, to_square
from PIL import Image

square = np.asarray(Image.open('Picture.png').convert('L'))
#square = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,2,2,2,0,0],[0,0,1,2,3,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.uint8)
resized_image = cv2.resize(square, (32, 32)) 

circle = to_circle(resized_image)

coords = np.argwhere(circle)
x_min, y_min = coords.min(axis=0)
x_max, y_max = coords.max(axis=0)
b = cropped = circle[x_min:x_max+1, y_min:y_max+1]
resized_cropped_image = cv2.resize(cropped, (32, 32)) 


fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10))

axs[0, 0].imshow(square)
axs[0, 0].set_title('Original')

axs[0, 1].imshow(resized_image)
axs[0, 1].set_title('Resized to 32x32')

axs[1, 0].imshow(circle)
axs[1, 0].set_title('Remapped to cicle')

axs[1, 1].imshow(resized_cropped_image)
axs[1, 1].set_title('Trimmed')
```